# convert js datetime to moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have this format of datetime currently stored in `res.data[i].time`:

```
2022-05-18T13:00:00.000Z
```

what I want to do is convert it to `moment` format. When i do this:

```
moment().toDate()
```

it gives me this:

```
Tue May 10 2022 13:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)
```

what I want to need to do is convert `2022-05-18T13:00:00.000Z` to moment somehow. I tried:

```
moment().toDate(res.data[i].time)
```

but that doesn't work either. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `let whatever = moment(res.data[i].time)` should instantiate the `moment` object with the time string provided. You can then do whatever you need from there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use momentjs in any tag

```
<h3>{{  moment(res.data[i].time).format("DD.MM.YYYY")  }}</h3>
```

and returns to you (approximately today's date)

```
11.05.2022
```

to get acquainted with detailed formats:

[momentJs all formats](https://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what Moment supports now.

```
moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC
moment('24/12/2019 09:15:00', "DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss");
moment('24/12/2019 09:15:00', "DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss", true);
.
.
.
```

See this doc -> https://momentjs.com/docs/